# How do I make my Linked List Print backwards in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

How do I make my program print the Linked List backwards? I got the printForward function working fine but the printBackwards function just doesn't seem to do anything. I think I'm on the right track but I'm a little stuck right now. I think the while loop isn't running because temp is NULL for some reason.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

List.h

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class LinkedList
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        int data;
        Node * next;
        Node * prev;
    };
    Node * head, *tail;
public:
    LinkedList();
    bool addAtBeginning(int val);
    bool remove(int val);
    void printForward() const;
    void printBackward() const;
};
#endif
```

List.cpp

```
#include "List.h"

LinkedList::LinkedList()
{
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
}

bool LinkedList::addAtBeginning(int val)
{
    Node* temp;
    temp = new Node;

    temp->data = val;
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;

    return false;
}

bool LinkedList::remove(int val)
{

    return false;
}

void LinkedList::printForward() const
{
    Node* temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        cout << temp->data << " ";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void LinkedList::printBackward() const
{
    Node* temp = tail;

    while (temp != NULL) {

        cout << temp->data << " ";
        temp = temp->prev;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

app.cpp

```
#include "list.h"

int main()
{
    LinkedList aList;

    aList.addAtBeginning(3);
    aList.addAtBeginning(10);
    aList.addAtBeginning(1);
    aList.addAtBeginning(7);
    aList.addAtBeginning(9);
    aList.addAtBeginning(12);
    aList.printForward();
    aList.printBackward();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: addAtBeginning never sets tail so it always remains NULL

Comment: It looks like the `prev` members are never set either.

Comment: What would I set them to? Sorry im a little lost in the logic

Answer (score 0):

I find it a bit odd that you only have an `addAtBeginning` method, and no method to add at the end, the latter which I would consider to be normal use of a linked list.  That being said, I think the immediate problem here is that you never assign the `tail` to anything.  Try this version of `addAtBeginning`:

```
bool LinkedList::addAtBeginning(int val)
{
    Node* temp;
    temp = new Node;

    temp->data = val;
    temp->next = head;
    if (head != NULL)
    {
        head->prev = temp;
    }
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        tail = temp;
    }
    head = temp;

    return false;
`}
```

The logic here is that for the first addition to an empty list, we assign the head and tail to the initial node.  Then, in subsequent additions, we add a new element to the head of the list, and then assign both the `next` and `prev` pointers, to link the new node in both directions.  This should allow you to iterate the list backwards, starting with the tail.

Answer (score 0):

Update addAtBeginning function with given:

```
bool LinkedList::addAtBeginning(int val)
{
    Node* temp;
    temp = new Node;
    temp->data = val;
    temp->prev = temp->next = NULL;


    //  If adding first node, then head is NULL. 
    //  Then, set Head and Tail to this new added node
    if(head == NULL){
        // If this linked list is circular
        temp->next = temp->prev = temp;

        head = tail = temp;

    }else{ // If we already have at least one node in the list

        // If this linked list is circular
        temp->prev = head->prev;

        temp->next = head;
        head->prev = temp;
        head = temp;
    }

    return false;
}
```

But remember, if you copy this function with the parts that it makes this list circular, you will get an infinite loop. So, either change print function or dont copy that parts.